# Failed to understand heroku slugsize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently pushed a new and empty app with gemfile added up to heroku and it was added successfully. The folder size locally is 488kb but on heroku its slugsize is 6mb of 100mb. I did this after trying to push my real application that kept showing this error: fatal: sha1 file '' write error invalid argument. The size of this app locally is 3mb. Could this really be the problem why it isn't bing pushed. How on earth do i reduce this size even after adding .gitignore and .slugignore files. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details on the slug size can be found here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

The key part you might be interested in is:

> You can roughly estimate slug size locally by doing a fresh checkout
> of your app, deleting the .git directory, and running du -hsc.
>
> ```
> $ du -hsc | grep total
> ```

You get 200mb maximum though, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Still slugsize matter since, as heroku explains, the smallest the fastest load